# How to set the system background color below presented view controllers in ios 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

See the pic below, i presented a viewcontroller in my app, here comes 3 layers on screen:

1. Black, provided by system
2. My app, the presenting view controller, white
3. My app, the presented view controller, white

My question is, shouldn't the first layer be a blurred screen shot of a previously running app, why it's black? can i set the color?

[image: screenshot]

---

Edit: it turns out the first layer is not provided by system, but simply app's key window background! see my answer below

Comment: Why don't you change the background color of your presenting view controller (or it's navigationbar) before presenting the new view controller? When you dismiss the new view controller, you should reset to the original background again. However, the whole approach seems to work against the design intentions of Apple's new view controller pesentations. If you are not happy with the background view controller showing, just present the new vc with fullscreen.

Comment: Sorry i didn't make it clear, i've update the question, i'm talking about the system background not the presenting layer. thanks for the reply anyway

Comment: Check out this [tutorial](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/change-color-status-bar-ios-tutorial), it might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it's actually not related to status bar, and only happens in ios 13, see my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to solve it by setting the key window background color, e.g.:

```swift
// inside appDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
// The first layer will be white now
window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: Doesn't work for AppDelegate if the window and other components are being created programatycally

Answer (score 0):

In the `viewWillAppear` of the root view controller, you need to reset background color of it by put the code bellow:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

In put this at where you push the new view controller:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(anotherVC, completion: {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .black
        })
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't make it clear, i've update the question, i'm talking about the system background not the presenting layer, thanks for the answer anyway!